# consuming WCF service in .net 2.0 windows application

Tags: wcf, .net-2.0

I'm new in WCF service and I need to consume the WCF service from my client for my current .net 2.0 windows app. I successfully added the WCF service as web reference in my .net 2.0 application but when using the web method of the service it took long time to execute the method and in the end my application is not responding. Base on the request in fiddler, the request has been timed out. My client provides me a user name and password but I don't know where to use it. Base on the wcf web service wsdl of my client, it uses WSHttpBinding.

I also created a sample .net 4.0 windows application and added the service as reference but still cannot use the web method. I check also the request in fiddler and gives me a response error "The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.".

Please help. I need to consume the WCF service using my existing .net 2.0 application.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you add some sample code on how you connect to this service and your client app.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consume your WCF service from .NET 2.0 via adding web reference you must use `BasicHttpBinding` - that is only backward compatible build-in binding (except custom defined binding) with ASMX based client.

Your exception in case of .NET 4.0 test complains about security token - `WsHttpBinding` uses Windows security by default. It is hard to diagnose the problem further because you didn't provide enough information.

Comment: Ok, when using .net 4.0. I was able to pass the ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName and ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password using the user name and password given by my client. But It gives me an exception "The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state."